# Jquery appendTo this.$el is overriding the previous script.

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I am new to Jquery and JavaScript. I was asked to add new screen using the existing code.

```
_initWidgets: function() {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.sendScreenA = SendScreenA().appendTo(this.$el);
        this.sendScreenB = SendScreenB().appendTo(this.$el);
        return this;
    },
```

above code correctly generating two kind of screens based on the selection.

I have added an extra entry to the above code to generate third screen.

```
this.sendScreenC = SendScreenC().appendTo(this.$el);
```

when I added the above line its breaking code, but if I comment out this.sendScreenB line its working fine.

Can someone guide me how to fix this.

Comment: "when I added the above line its breaking code" what does this mean? do you have some error to show?

Comment: screen is not loading and getting `Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined` error  for  `self.get('model').validate(visible).then(function() {
                    self.set('currentPane', self.get('currentPane')+1);
                }, self.processErrors);`

Comment: The impression is that the error is generated due to the internal code of SendScreenA SendScreenB and SendScreenC. Without the code for these three object it is not possible to understand the error

Comment: its working fine when I use two screens, but not for three screens.

Comment: infact i used SendScreenB and duplicated it and renamed it as SendScreenC.